# Azure Recovery Services Vault Backup Usage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have started using the Azure Recovery Services Vault to backup some Azure VMs for the first time.  While looking at the vault I noticed in both recovery services vaults that the backup files were being stored in Cloud-GRS storage and not Cloud-LRS storage.  I've looked everywhere I can think of and I can't find a way to change it (or anything even saying why I would want to).  So, a couple of questions:

- Is it possible to change the backup destination to Cloud-LRS?
- If yes, why would one want to change it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change the backup destination to Cloud-LRS?

Once you have registered servers on it, no. You have to remove all protected items before switching vault type. By default, GRS is used.

Assuming you have no protected items, select the *Recovery Services Vault* >> *Backup Infrastructure* >> *Backup Configuration* >> *Select storage type*

> If yes, why would one want to change it?

Basically, you'd want to change it only if Azure is not your primary backup storage endpoint or if your backup data is not so critical after all.